# How are require, require_dependency and constants reloading related in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, require

**How are `require` and `require_dependency` different?**
How can `require_dependency` automatically reload classes in development but `require` can't ?

I digged into Rails' `ActiveSupport::Dependencies` and dispatcher.rb code. What I saw in `require_dependency`'s code is it basically adds the constants to an `autoloaded_constants` array. But it gets cleared in `clear_application` inside dispatcher after each request.

Can someone give a clear explanation or point me to some resources which will help?

Comment: FYI: The class reloading is automatically handled in engines (which are nothing but plugins with app/ folders), just like they are in normal apps.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah, I am aware of that. But then this leads to my other question: Can I use other plugins inside my plugin? Say, I want to use a act_as_xxx plugin in my own plugin, can I just put the act_as_xxx inside my plugin's vendor/plugins directory and then add the path to $LOAD_PATH? I guess I should ask this in another thread tho, it's unrelated to my original question.

Answer (score 140):

`require` (and its cousin `load`) are core Ruby methods. `require_dependency` is a method that helps Rails handle the problem of dependency management. Long story short, it allows Rails to reload classes in development mode so that you don't have to restart the server each time you make a code change. The Rails framework will `require_dependency` your code so that it can track and reload it when changes are made. The standard Ruby `require` doesn't do that. As an app (or plugin/engine) developer you should not have to worry about `require_dependency` as this is purely internal to Rails.

The magic of the Rails class loading process is in the ActiveSupport::Dependencies module.  This code extends the default Ruby behavior to allow code inside your Rails app to automatically load modules (including classes which inherit from Module) using Rails' path and file naming conventions. This eliminates the need for the programmer to litter their code with `require` calls like you would in a plain Ruby application.

To put it another way, this lets you define `class Admin::User` inside the file `app/models/admin/user.rb` and have Rails know what you are talking about when you call `Admin::User.new` from another part of the application like a controller. Without ActiveSupport::Dependencies involved you would have to manually `require` everything you needed.

If you are coming from a statically typed language like C#, Java, etc then this might be a surprise:  Rails code is not loaded until it is needed. For example, a `User` model class isn't defined and `user.rb` isn't loaded until AFTER you try to call `User.whatever_method_here`. Rails prevents Ruby from complaining about that missing constant, loads code for `User`, and then allows Ruby to continue as normal.

While I can't speak for your specific need, I would be very surprised if you actually needed to use the `require_dependency` method from within a plugin or engine. If you follow Rails conventions you shouldn't have to tweak the $LOAD_PATH by hand, either. This is not "the Rails way".

In the world of Ruby and also Rails simplicity and clarity is key. If all you want to do is write a plugin or engine and you are already diving deep into internals then you may consider approaching your problem from a different angle. My gut tells me that you may be trying to do something that is needlessly complicated. But then again, I have no clue what you are doing exactly!!  :)

Comment: `require_dependency` has been obsoleted in Rails 6, https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#require-dependency

Answer (score 26):

`require_dependency` is useful in an engine when you want to re-open a class which is not defined in your engine (for example in another engine or Rails app) and have it reloaded. In which case something like this works:

```
# app/controllers/my_engine/documents_controller.rb
require_dependency MyEngine::Engine.root.join('app', 'controllers', 'my_engine', 'documents_controller').to_s

module MyEngine
  class DocumentsController
    def show
      render :text => 'different'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `require_dependency` has been obsoleted in Rails 6, https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#require-dependency