# Where does config.to_prepare should go in Rails 3.1 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration

I'm trying to use a file that is supposed to be reloaded in development all the time and loaded in production once.

I'm trying to use

```
config.to_prepare do
  require File.expand_path('config/configatron.rb')
end
```

This allows for reloading of my configatron settings in dev.  However it's not working. meaning it's only loaded once, not being reloaded on page refreshes.  According to documentation it should. Right now I have it in my application.rb - is that the right place ? If yes does anyone what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I place my to_prepare blocks in initializers.

There is a problem with your code.

From *require* documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require

> The absolute path of the loaded file is added to $LOADED_FEATURES ($"). A file will not be loaded again if its path already appears in $". For example, require 'a'; require './a' will not load a.rb again.

Even when your block is called before each environment reload *require* won't load your *configuration.rb* file again.

Instead of using *to_prepare* you can try to rewrite your code using *require_dependency* [How are require, require_dependency and constants reloading related in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457241/how-are-require-require-dependency-and-constants-reloading-related-in-rails)

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 p 180 does it hold true for that version?